# How many rich people we Robin Hood at least see?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Every black tile is a house of a rich person and every white house is a house of a poor person if Robin Hood starts from black tile(not a constant one) and can move to the tiles next to it How many rich people we Rabin Hood at least see if he wants to pass from all white tiles.It is something bigger than $5$ because for passing the corner tiles we should go from a distinct black tile to go to them but then again we can't pass the center so we should pass at least $5$ black tiles
but I can't find the case that we pass from $5$ of them but I can find the case that we pass from $6$ of them.Is the answer $6$ or $5$.

Comment: By the way its Robin Hood you might be thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood

Comment: I would clarify the Question in a couple of ways.  It seems that Robin Hood is allowed to visit a tile more than once, but you count the same black tile only for one "rich person" no matter how many times the tile is visited.  Also the notion of "move to the tiles next to it" seems to mean tiles that share an edge (not merely a corner/vertex).

Comment: I don't get the problem at all. Why can't he just visit every tile and see all the black tiles?

Comment: @Kundor because we want the minimum of them.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You start on a black tile. You can move horizontally or vertically.  But what does it mean to "see" a black tile and what does "pass from all white tiles" mean?

Comment: @Jens We can't move vertically.

Comment: @TahaAkbari If you cannot move vertically than it is either impossible because you cannot leave the level you are at. Or trivial if you can travel diagonally. I think you mean we cannot travel diagonally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it is six, I can test it with a program  but ill also try to prove it. 
I'm assuming the first black square is counted as seen (included in the six).

If there is a path with only 5 black squares than necessarily all white squares need to be adjacent to that set. only paths that go trough this type of sets can be solutions. since we need for each corner at least one adjacent square we clearly need one square per corner. to connect all four corner-squares we need at least one square and we need at least one square from the middle to statisfy the middle square. lets drop the connection requirement and just look at sets that accomplish  the goal of covering all the white sets. clearly we need the five black squares to do this. More interestingly is that there is only a limited number of ways to do this. in essence only two.
first consider this picture with all the outer black squares being marked S or N (South and North) and all in black  squares with a number between 1 and 4.
[image]

1. In the first solution the center square choice doesn't matter, in this we choose the corner square so that it covers the entire outer layer. This means that all outer squares thats are next to each other horizontally have different letters and squares that are next to each other vertically have to have the same letter.
   Then we can add a random middle square to cover all white squares. However without the center square it is impossible to have a path between the chosen outer black squares. since the inner square can only connect two of them. it is impossible to construct a path in this cover set and so it is not applicable.
2. In the second solution we still need to pick four outer squares and one inner square. but we do not cover the entire the entire outer layer. It is clear that all white squares outside the outer layer are covered when the corners are covered except for the very center. however we can choose to not cover some white squares that are not corners but are on the outside layer. since the center square can only cover one of these we need to cover the other three. 
   this means we can divert from the previous solution but only with one square. this means we still have three non adjacents sets and just one connection in the form of the center square so we can still not make a path.

Comment: Please ask if something is unclear , I typed this when I was quite sleepy.